# Spark Scala fill NA with today timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I replace all the null values in a column of type timestamp?

I expected this to be easier but I can't seem to get the types correctly.
I assume a solution would be to convert the column to String, fill with today's date in string and then reconvert to timestamp but, is there a more elegant solution?

```scala
val today = java.time.LocalDate.now()
var todayStamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(today.atStartOfDay());
df = df.na.fill(Map("expiration" -> todayStamp))
```

results in

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value type java.sql.Timestamp
```

using today doesn't work either and using `unix_timestamp(string).cast("timestamp")`
expects a column instead of a string. I think I can use this in the "ugly" method I mentioned above.

LATER EDIT:
Forgot to mention, using Int or String with the df.na.fill method on a timestamp column results in an error too:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'coalesce(expiration, 0)' due to data type mismatch: input to function coalesce should all be the same type, but it's [timestamp, int];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [coalesce](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@coalesce(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("expiration", coalesce(col("expiration"), current_timestamp()))
```

Here's a reproducible example:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  Tuple1(None: Option[Timestamp]),
  Tuple1(Some(Timestamp.valueOf("2010-01-01 00:00:00")))
).toDF("expiration")

df.withColumn("expiration", coalesce(col("expiration"), current_timestamp())).show()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution generates the following failure:

Comment: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainLongDictionary` (hit enter too soon and no edit priviledge, sry)

Comment: @UrVal That's weird. There was a typo in my code, hopefully it was the cause for your problem

Comment: No :) I fixed that before running but the problem appears due to the data I have to work with. The code you recommended might still be good but I have to find a way around the issue above first

Answer (score 2):

According to the document:

**The value must be of the following type: Integer, Long, Float, Double, String, Boolean**. **Replacement values are cast to the column data type.**

Using na.fill - you'll need to provide the date as integer,Long or String, and it is possible that if the column is of type "timestamp" it will be casted automatically to be "timestamp"

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html

**fill**

```
public Dataset<Row> fill(java.util.Map<String,Object> valueMap)
```

Returns a new DataFrame that replaces null values.

The key of the map is the column name, and the value of the map is the replacement value. **The value must be of the following type: Integer, Long, Float, Double, String, Boolean**. *Replacement values are cast to the column data type*.

For example, the following replaces null values in column "A" with string "unknown", and null values in column "B" with numeric value 1.0.

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
df.na.fill(ImmutableMap.of("A", "unknown", "B", 1.0));
```

Comment: I guess I forgot to write in the initial post. Trying na.fill with the value 0 gives the error:
`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'coalesce(`expiration`, 0)' due to data type mismatch: input to function coalesce should all be the same type, but it's [timestamp, int];`
I did read the docs before posting but thank you for the refresh

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simple:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("expiration", 
  when($"expiration".isNull, current_timestamp()).otherwise($"expiration"))
```

Comment: This is more elegant but I have a different error now `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDicti‌​onary$PlainLongDicti‌​onary` I'll try your solution again after fixing the code above

Answer (score -1):

I could do this in Java by first casting column values to String, then replacing the null string with a default using df.na() and then casting the column back as timestamp.

Input Data

```
+-------------------+
|               date|
+-------------------+
|               null|
|2018-04-03 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

My Transformation

```
df.withColumn(
    "stringDate", 
    col("date").cast(DataTypes.StringType))
        .na().fill("2018-04-01 00:00:00")
        .withColumn("finalDate", col("stringDate").cast(DataTypes.TimestampType))
        .select("finalDate");
```

Final Output

```
+-------------------+
|          finalDate|
+-------------------+
|2018-04-01 00:00:00|
|2018-04-03 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for reading the question, especially this part: "I assume a solution would be to convert the column to String, fill with today's date in string and then reconvert to timestamp but, is there a more elegant solution?"